# How to fix it wsl ubuntu on windows 10? Operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using a WSL, ubuntu on windows 10 and I want to set permissions like below but I am receiving an error.
Why? How do I fix it?

```
ubuntu-user@LAPTOP:~$ chmod 400 .ssh/MyKey.pem
chmod: changing permissions of '.ssh/MyKey.pem': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: You are probably not the owner of the file. Edit your question and include the output of `ls -la ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use these commands in only one session, every time when you open terminal, you have to enter again. I solved my issue with this way.

```
sudo umount /mnt/c
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
chmod 400 [fileName] or chmod 700 [fileName]
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610256/chmod-wsl-bash-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo chmod 400 .ssh/MyKey.pem`